# Identify & delete Blank sheets

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using [PhpExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com) to generate xls files.
What I am doing right now is....

1. Create sheets from A to Z
2. Loop through all Members in site and get first character of firstname
3. Using the first character I decide sheet index and activate that sheet.
4. Then append that users name and add related analytic data in it.

Now I want to remove all those sheets which do not have any data.

How do I find which sheets are blank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to loop through the cells in each sheet testing each in turn, because PHPExcel doesn't provide any built-in method to test if a sheet is blank

But why not create sheets only when you need to create a sheet, that would be a lot more efficient than creating a set of sheets at the start of your script, and then (at the end) deleting those that you haven't used

```
1. Loop through all Members in site and get first character of firstname
2. Using the first character, test if the sheet you need exists 
    - create it if necessary
3. Then append that users name and add related analytic data in it.
```

If your members are looped in alphabetic order, then you don't even need to reorder the sheets when you've finished

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mark.
Yes I thought about it but the problem is my member are not in alphabetical order. I am using wordpress wishlist plugin it has api function named wlmapi_get_members(){http://codex.wishlistproducts.com/function-reference-wlmapi_get_member/} it returns users array but no firstname and lastname. I have to use another function to fetch it.

Comment: That still doesn't preclude only creating sheets when necessary, it just means that you'll need to order the sheets after you've finished populating them

Comment: The PHPExcel object's `setIndexByName()` method allows you to modify the ordering of worksheets

Comment: Okay Mark I will try it and let you know. Thanks again! :)